# SSRS how to add in New line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a string from stored procedure like this `Name1 , Name2 , Name 3....` etc(This string is in one column).
I want to display these name in a new line in my SSRS report like

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

I tried changing the string to

```
Name1 VbCrlf 
Name2 VbCrlf  
Name 3
```

Doesn't seems to be working.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use an expression like:

```
=Replace(Field!Names.Value, ",", VbCrLf)
```

Comment: Good tip. This is how I used it in an expression to show the selections from a multi-value parameter. ="Name:" + VbCrLf + Join(Parameters!Names.Value, VbCrLf)

Answer (score 0):

```
="Name1:"+ Fields!name1field.Value + VbCrLf  +
"Name2:"+ Fields!name2field.Value + VbCrLf  +
"Name3:"+ Fields!name3field.Value + VbCrLf  +
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for displaying each multivalue parameter on a new line

```
=Join(Parameters!<YourMultiValueParameterNameHere>.Value, VbCrLf)
```

Hope this helps, Snelly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this 

`="Name1:" & VbCrLf & 
"Name2:"& VbCrLf &
"Name3:"& VbCrLf`