# SQL Report Builder add line break to expressions

Tags: sql, reporting-services

The expression currently used to populate the cell in the report is as follows:

```
=Fields!SomeDataFromSQL.Value
```

Now the value of that `.Value` is something like below:

```
Image01 Image02 Image03 Image04
```

I would like for these to appear in the report as new line items for readability:

```
Image01
Image02
Image03
Image04
```

How can I build this into the query?

Comment: either you should use `Environment.NewLine` OR `="Image01" & vbcrlf & "Image01"  OR  `CHR(13)` in your sql query

Comment: If I put that into my SQL cell, in the report it just appears as exactly as you put it there: ="Image01" & vbcrlf & "Image01"

Comment: Instead of that, you can use <br/>  in SQL query and use placeholder to set value. Also check radio button of html text inside placeholder properties... It will definitely work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS how to add in New line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306328/ssrs-how-to-add-in-new-line)